# WordPress: delete custom post in frontend with custom user role not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am building a custom frontend where custom role `members` (created with [User Role Editor](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)) can add and edit `spots`.

"Spots" are a custom post type registered like this:

```php
 register_post_type('spot',
   array(
       'labels'          => array( ... ),
       'supports'        => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
       'public'          => true,
       'has_archive'     => true,
       'capability_type' => array('spot', 'spots'),
       'map_meta_cap'    => true,
    )
  );
```

Now adding and editing these spots works great, but I fail to create a delete link like this:

```php
echo '<a href="'. get_delete_post_link($post->ID) .'">Delete</a>';
```

This doesn't echo anything at all unless I am logged in as admin, in which case it works as intended.

I have tried to look into this with `current_user_can()` with these results:

```php
get_current_user_id() == $post->post_author => true
current_user_can( 'delete_posts', $post->ID ) => true
current_user_can( 'delete_post', $post->ID )  => false
current_user_can( 'delete_spots', $post->ID ) => true
current_user_can( 'delete_spot', $post->ID )  => false
```

I assume the singular version is correct and that failing the check where my problem lies. But should I query for `delete_post` or `delete_spot`?

I am editing the `member` capabilities with User Role Editor as well and have added both `delete_posts` and `delete_spots` capabilities to the role. Other capabilities such as `upload_files` can be granted and revoked correctly through the interface.

I have to add that I am prohibiting members to access `/wp-admin` using the [User Registration](https://wpuserregistration.com/) plugin. While lifting the restriction does not make the delete link appear, I have read elsewhere that prohibiting backend access also makes the delete link dysfunctional, as it depends on `/wp-admin` access. Not sure if this would be true if I could make it appear.

What I'm looking for:

1. Help with the syntax and some more detailed way to investigate `member` capabilities. I cannot rule out that I have introduced some permission conflict for the role by trying out different user registration plugins. E.g. where are capabilities stored in the DB and are they human readable?
2. Another way to make a delete link (perhaps using AJAX?). Not sure if this would work if the proper capability is missing, but if `get_delete_post_link()` is not compatible with restricting the backend than I would need a different method anyway.

Thank you!

Comment: As you notice get_delete_post_link is for backend. If you want to delete a post try using wp_delete_post(). Create button to trigger it ajax. If you want to be moved in trash then use wp_trash_post.

Comment: get_delete_post_link is for backend -> why, because it needs wp-admin access? I shall try an AJAX wp_delete_post solution, but I am still concerned about the capability problem...

Comment: If you go to the function documentation you will see its requesting admin_url to generate the link so if you dont have access to backend that cant happen right ? What concerns you have about the capabilities ? Which one ?

Comment: Also if you try to delete post that you are not author or moderator or admin you may need to add that capability but that depends how you want it to work.